# Es posible reiniciar el equipo dónde se encuentra mi servidor?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo un proyecto ReactAdmin y node.js. El cual procesa un data.json para realizar acciones CRUD.
Luego de que se actualice el data.json con los nuevos datos me están pidiendo que se reinicia el equipo. Cómo se puede ejecutar esto con un botón desde la web?.

Estuve probando realizar lo siguiente en mi servidor node.js
Agregué:

```
// # RESTART VM

app.post('/restart-vm', (req, res) => {

  // El siguiente comando reiniciará la máquina.

  exec('sudo reboot', (error, stdout, stderr) => {

    if (error) {

      console.error(`Error al reiniciar la VM: ${error.message}`);

      res.status(500).send('Error al reiniciar la VM');

      return;

    }

    console.log('VM reiniciada con éxito');

    res.send('Reiniciando VM...');

  });

});
```

Y en mi proyecto de react admin agregué ReiniciarVmButton.js

```
// ReiniciarVMButton.js

import React from 'react';

import { Button } from 'react-admin';



const ReiniciarVmButton = () => {

  const handleReiniciarClick = async () => {

    try {

      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4002/restart-vm', {

        method: 'POST',

      });



      if (response.ok) {

        console.log('Solicitud de reinicio enviada con éxito');

        // Puedes realizar cualquier acción adicional después de que la solicitud sea exitosa

      } else {

        console.error('Error al enviar la solicitud de reinicio');

      }

    } catch (error) {

      console.error('Error de red:', error);

    }

  };



  return (

    <Button label="Reiniciar VM" onClick={handleReiniciarClick} />

  );

};



export default ReiniciarVmButton;
```

Esto me está lanzado este error:

XHRPOST
http://localhost:4002/restart-vm
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]

Error al enviar la solicitud de reinicio ReiniciarVmButton.js:16
XHRPOST
http://localhost:4002/restart-vm
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]

Error al enviar la solicitud de reinicio

No comprendo muy bien cómo se realizan este tipo de acciones para apagar el equipo. Agradezco cualquier solución que me puedan brindar.

Por otro lado, cómo se gestiona el reinicio si no le proporciono la contraseña y usuario del equipo?

Gracias

Comment: Recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar [ask]. Puedes también obtener reputación para preguntar por una opinión en [chat].

Comment: Pedir reiniciar un equipo de esa forma, es muy raro... cual es el motivo para reiniciarlo?

Comment: Sinceramente no tengo acceso a la otra parte del proyecto. Pero cuando se actualiza el .json el otro sistema necesita que el equipo haga un reboot.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: 404 es que no encontro la ruta... no tiene nada que ver con el reinicio.. igual, supongamos que ejecuta el reinicio.. pum.. se acabo, no hay respuesta, no hay nada, se reinicio, no podes saber que paso despues... no hay respuesta a mandar, no hay nada.. el node se reinicio, es como si apretaras reset... no vas a saber que paso... y eso, si tenes permisos suficientes para hacerlo...

Comment: Si, eso de los permisos creo que es el problema. Pero no se cómo se establecen, porque en el código no debería de ponerlos.
Saber si se reinicio, voy a saberlo, porque dejearia de funcionar parte de la web y además es una VM que tengo instalada en mi computadora, podría ver el reinicio.
El problema es que no lo está haciendo. Además la respuesta llega al servidor, porque en la consola recibe la solicitud POST, pero no hace nada.

Comment: estas pensando esto en un ambiente corporativo, donde la pobre gente usando ese sistema de pronto se queda sin sistema?? el reinicio deberia ser pautado por alguna especie de cron del sistema operativo donde resida esa virtual.. pero bueno... no sabria que decirte, el 404 es no se encuentra la ruta...

Comment: Mirá, yo no tengo la posibilidad de decir. Che... no hagamos esto porque no tiene sentido. A mi me dice hagamos esto y lo hago. Por otro lado... Lo arregle permitiendo desde sudoers que no solicite passwd.
ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
E
Hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Igualmente entiendo que esto lo usuario 1 sóla, persona. Así que se si reinicia el equipo, es porque él lo necesitó